# Reading JSON data into Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following piece of code in a function to read in a JSON file:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = this.responseText;
        console.log(myObj);
        JSON.parse(myObj); // error is here
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "music-data.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The JSON data is coming locally from the same folder as my html/css/js files, and is structured as:

```
window.MUSIC_DATA = {
  "list1": [
    {
        data here...
   },
 ],
  "list2": [
    { data here...
 ...
}
```

I am unable to parse my object and extract what I need from list1 and list2 and get an error with the existing code:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: remove `window.MUSIC_DATA =` part in your json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated you need to fix your server side file to be a valid JSON. If you have no control over the contents of this file and want to avoid string manipulation routines here's an alternative approach that you could use:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'music-data.json';
s.async = true;
s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
    if (!s.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(s.readyState)) {
        var myObj = window['MUSIC_DATA'];
        console.log(myObj);

        alert(myObj.list1);
        alert(myObj.list2);
        ...
    }
};
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with

```
window.MUSIC_DATA =
```

That's not JSON, it's JavaScript. Remove that from the file so that only the value is left, and it may work (or there may be other problems with the file).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
window.MUSIC_DATA = {
  "list1": [
    {
        data here...
   },
 ],
  "list2": [
    { data here...
 ...
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "list1": [
    {
        data here...
   },
 ],
  "list2": [
    { data here...
 ...
}
```